# Regex for URL to get ID

Tags: regex, url

I am new to Regex. I have a few easy expressions written for urls. I am having some trouble writing one if the URL has a category and then a random html page after the ID:

http://www.website.com/MajorCategory/MinorCateory/118326/title-of-page.html

I am trying to match the 6 digit id in the example above. any help on getting this to match would be awesome.

Comment: What tool/language are you using for regex?

Comment: i am writing them for a PHP script. A good example of what I am trying to write would be a ID match for DailyMotion. The script embeds videos to a website. Here is the DailyMotion example:
  array (
    'title' => 'Dailymotion',
    'website' => 'http://www.dailymotion.com',
    'url-match' => 'http://(?:www\.)?dailymotion\.(?:com|alice\.it)/(?:(?:[^"]*?)?video|swf)/([a-z0-9]{1,18})',
    'embed-src' => 'http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/$2&related=0',
    'embed-width' => '420',
    'embed-height' => '339',
    'image-src' => 'http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/160x120/video/$2' 
  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
'~[0-9]+(?=/[^/]*$)~'
```

#### Working Demo: http://regex101.com/r/wY4mH3

**PHP Code:**

```
if ( preg_match('~[0-9]+(?=/[^/]*$)~', $str, $m) )
   echo ($m[0]);
```